# How do I ensure db call is completed before using db.colse() [in node.js to access mongo.db]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database

```
var storedArticleArray = db.collection('storedArticle').find(query).toArray;
console.dir(storedArticleArray);
db.close();
```

How can I ensure that `console.dir(stroedArticleArray)` displays its argument only after the database completed the query and stored the result in `storedArticleArray`?

Also `db.close()` does not close before the query is completed.

Does this work:

```
var storedArticleArray = db.collection('').find(query).toArray(function() {
    console.dir(storedArticleArray);
    db.close();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You must use Node.js callback functions when you query your MongoDB database, because they're asynchronous operations.

Following your example you can use:

```
var storedArticleArray = [];
db.collection('storedArticle').find(query, function(error, data) {
    storedArticleArray = data.toArray;
    console.dir(storedArticleArray);
    db.close();
});
```

The callback function will be executed once the query will be completed and returned data (or an error, that you must always handle). In the callback you'll be sure to close the db connection without problems.

Comment: How do you know the call back function can have two arguments and second is a pointer. I am a beginner in JS. Which document says that?[edit]
I got the source.. https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/queries.html